General solution for linear Volterra-like integral equation?
A linear Volterra integral equation looks like this (see the wiki)
\begin{align}
     x(t) = f(t) + \int_0^t K(t, s)x(s)~\mathrm{d}s.
\end{align}
If the Kernel function $K$ is of the form $K(t, s) = K(t - s)$, then the integral is a convolution, and the Volterra equation can be solved using laplace transforms. In this case the general solution is
\begin{align}
     \mathscr{L}[x](s) = \frac{\mathscr{L}[f](s)}{1 - \mathscr{L}[K](s)},
\end{align}
where $\mathscr{L}[x](s) = \int_0^{\infty} x(t)e^{-st}\mathrm{d}t$ is the laplace transform of $x$, evaluated at $s$.
My question is, is there a simimlar/alternative way of dealing with the following integral equation
\begin{align}
     x(t) = f(t) + \int_0^1 K(t, s)x(s)~\mathrm{d}s,
\end{align}
where $t,s \in [0, 1]$? Or a way of mapping this problem onto the first? In particular, is there a similarly nice solution when $K(t, s) = K(t-s)$? Any help or resources are appreciated.

I guess you want $K(t,s)$ instead of $K(t-s)$ in the last displayed equation?

You're right, I've edited the question. Hopefully its clearer now.
